# Why I have to use vs2005 for InfoPath2010 programming

Tags: infopath

Hi Any reasones that I have to use vs2005 for InfoPath2010 programming.Is there a settings that I can let infopath to open VS2010 instead of VS2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have VS2008 it will still work, but as of 2010 InfoPath development in VS is no longer an option.  It's unfortunate.

EDIT: Are you referring to developing the InfoPath template within Visual Studio (because I was), or putting code behind in your template from within the InfoPath Designer?  I'm guessing the latter after thinking about it.  If that is the case, ignore my previous comment. The same thing just happened to me. I have Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0 installed. I wonder if uninstalling it would take care of it...